# Did Apple sue New York city over the nickname Big Apple?

Tags: computers, law, commerce, apple-inc

An article in The Guardian - [Apple's rot starts with its Samsung lawsuit win](http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2012/aug/28/apple-rot-starts-with-samsung-lawsuit-win)

Makes the following claim:

> Apple is one of the most aggressive intellectual property litigators of all time
>   ... It's sued about the lower case "i"; it's sued about the word "pod"; it's sued New York City over the "big Apple"

**Did Apple sue New York City over the "Big Apple"?** Looking at the Wikipedia entry for [Big Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Apple) the nickname has been around since the 1920's, so I don't see how Apple could sue over it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Apple Inc. did sue NYC, however it was not about "Big Apple" nickname, but the logo that went along with it — a stylized apple.

[image: GreeNYC vs Apple]

> Apple filed a federal challenge to New York's trademark application
>   for a new "Big Apple" logo, saying it's too similar to the stylized
>   emblem found on iPhones, iPods and iMac computers.
>
> Cupertino, Calif.-based Apple said the symbol for New York's "GreeNYC"
>   initiative promoting energy efficiency and recycling is confusingly
>   similar to the logo used by the electronics maker since 1977.
>
> NYC & Company Inc., the city's nonprofit tourism and marketing office,
>   filed the trademark application in May, playing off of New York's "Big
>   Apple" nickname.
>
> New York already has begun using the logo, which morphs the symbol for
>   infinity (similar to a figure 8 on its side) with the outline of an
>   apple, a stem and a single leaf. 
>   [...]

Source: ["Apple sues New York over logo"](http://articles.latimes.com/2008/apr/04/business/fi-apple4), LA Times

At the same time Apple filled opposition in USPTO, 
[which sided with NYC, dismissing the opposition.](http://ttabvue.uspto.gov/ttabvue/ttabvue-91181984-OPP-9.pdf)

The story was also [covered on Wired.com](http://www.wired.com/techbiz/it/news/2008/04/apple_vs_apple#).

Comment: Wow, those two logos don't even look remotely the same...

Comment: @Izkata - There is an awful lot of similarity but I don't think that anyone would confuse the two.  From a graphic's perspective the exterior edge of the NYC logo matches well, almost too well, with the Apple logo.